# How i can add a new object by POST request and mongoose with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have no idea ho i can do this with `.Router()` . I was just enough for `getById` 
I need create route on POST request on this, yay?

**./generalRepository.js**

```
function Repository() {}

Repository.prototype.getById = getById;

function getById(id, callback) {
  var model = this.model;
  var query = model.findOne({
    _id: id
  });
  query.exec(callback);
}
```

**.routers/user.js**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const userService = require("../../services/user");



router.get("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  userService.findOne(String(req.params.id), (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.data = data;
      console.log("это запрос в айди");
      res.json(res.data);
    } else {
      console.log(Number(req.params.id));
      res.status(400);
      res.end();
    }
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

**.services/user.js**

```
module.exports = {
  findAll: callback => {

  findOne: (id, callback) => {
    UserRepository.getById(id, (err, data) => {
      callback(err, data);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: What's the question? What do you mean by `add a new object`?

Comment: @Jeremy Thille  for example add all `body` from my `POST` by `insertOne` in mongoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example to POST data to Node and insert it using Mongoose :

```
// Add these two lines so your request's body can be accessed as JSON using req.body :
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '1mb' }));

(new myMongooseModel(req.body)).save( (error, result) => {
      if(error) return res.json(error);
      res.json(result);
})
```